# jQuery Datatables - how to check if row with given id is on the current page

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to check to see if a row with an known ID is present on the page that datatables is currently displaying

I'm using the following code

`let target = table.row('#'+ ns.currentClientId, {page:'current'});`

When I look at `target.data()` it always seems to contain the row identified by the "id" column, regardless of whether it is on the currently displayed page or not.

Am I misunderstanding / misusing the API?

[Here's a fiddle that isolates the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/6u45eahd/1/)

The data in the table is populated via an API call, and the id is set using the rowId property when the DataTable is created.

```
let table = $(selector).DataTable({
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/api/client/v1/client",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "dataSrc": "items",
                        "beforeSend": function (request) {
                            Object.keys(headers).forEach(function (key) {
                                request.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    "order": [],
                    retrieve: true,
                    "select": true,
                    select: {
                        style: 'single'
                    },
                    stateSave: true,
                    info: false,
                    lengthChange: false,
                    ordering: false,
                    rowId: "id",
                    "columns": [
                        {"data": "name"},
                        {"data": "dateofbirth"},
                        {
                            "data": "id",
                            "visible": false
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

When rendered, the HTML looks like this ( snippet )

[image]

Comment: This looks fine to me.. How do you initially set the id? Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: @F.H. - I've edited the question to show how the table is instantiated. It'll take me a little while to set up a fiddle. Would you expect target.data() to return an empty array if the row with the specified id didn't exist on the current pge?

Comment: it probably would help already if you posted a small snipped of some of the rendered html rows

Comment: @F.H. - Added rendered HTML

Comment: @F.H. - Added a fiddle to isolate the problem as well

Comment: very strange indeed.. i didn't see an example of using .row() with {page:'current'} but using it with rows() as shown in the examples just crashes the page.

Comment: one hacky solution would be to just check with jquery if given id occurs in the rendered rows. see: https://jsfiddle.net/ha7nvces/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to break JSFiddle trying to solve this! How very odd! Anyway, I think this should do what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "drawCallback": function (settings) {
      $('#tiger').hide();
      var api = this.api();
      api.rows({ page: 'current' }).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
        var rowNode = this.node();
        if ($(rowNode).attr('id') === 'id_1') {
          $('#tiger').show();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I'm using the built-in `drawCallback` function to iterate over the rows and get the raw HTML used to generate the DataTable.

Working example (hint: I've changed your CSS to remove the flash): https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/6ex5bkzq/